# Не запускается виртуальный эмулятор в Android Studio AMD Windows7

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, amd, hyper-v

Не устанавливается Android Emulator Hypervision Driver

Он вроде как устанавливается, но после установки не чего не происходит

При запуске выдает: Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Опять начинается установка и после нечего не происходит, опять вылетает этаже ошибка

Гипер-V к сожалению нет, так как у меня 7-ка стоит.

Виртуализацию в БИОСе включал, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Гипер-V нужен.

Обновитесь до 10 или переустановите Windows 10